# Use DataGridView.SelectedRows as DataSource for another DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to use the user-selected rows from one DataGridView as the DataSource for a second DataGridView. Note both DataGridViews will have identical columns.

Obviously I can iterate over the selected rows, obtain the key values, and re-query the database for a List to use as the DataSource of the 2nd grid, but that seems lame.

Surely there is an elegant way of simply re-using the SelectedRows collection as a DataSource?

Comment: `SelectedRows` is a simple collection without notifications (compared to `BindingSource`), so you will have to in any case handle event when it's changed (rised by `DataGridView`) to at least update `BindingSource`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly set collection of `DataRow` as datasource, you can read more details from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

How about doing (bit) traditional way?

```
var dt = ((DataTable)dataGrid1.DataSource).Clone();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid1.SelectedRows)
{
     dt.ImportRow(((DataTable)dataGrid1.DataSource).Rows[row.Index]);
}

dt.AcceptChanges();

dataGrid2.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Why using index if you already have `DataRow` object from `DataGridViewRow` As `dt.ImportRow((DataRow)row.DataBoundItem);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using [CopyToDataTable method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx).

```
DataTable dtable2;
DataRow[] rowArray = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
If !(rowArray.Length == 0 )
{
    dTable2 = rowArray.CopyToDataTable();
}

dataGrodView2.DataSource = dTable2;
```

Comment: I got:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection' to 'System.Data.DataRow[]'

Comment: Sorry our time zones seem to be different. Well, you could do a `cast`. Just updated my answer, also you already have the solution using linq :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. Seems there isn't a very simple way.

I did it this way:

```
MyDatGridView.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(dgvr => (int)dgvr.Cells[0].Value).ToList());
```

Then I tried to use the resulting List with a .Contains in a .Where clause.